# why are those removed files not found in any package?

Tags: centos, data-recovery

Accidentally i removed files from /usr/local/bin in a custom OS based on Centos 6.4 release, then i tried to figure out which package used the files (python scripts):

```
/bin/rpm -qa | while read f;do /bin/rpm -ql $f | grep "usr/local/bin"&&echo -e"  $f";done   
    /usr/local/bin
      filesystem-2.4.30-3.el6.x86_64
```

So, no luck. Then installed a minimal centos in a Virtual Box but /usr/local/bin it was empty, how do i get some clue what files where there?

Comment: You could look in /usr/local/man and /usr/local/lib to get some idea of what the programs were.

Answer (score 3):

Files under /usr/local are not belonging to any of packages. This direcory is used for custom program, scripts that you will install eg. from source code.
http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-4.9.html